# iterate each into each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to reiterate the table within herself. But it's not working. When I pass the parameter it will not go wrong or better.

```
 $('table tr').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this)
    var nivel = parseInt(tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
    var item = parseInt(tr.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    if (nivel > 3) {
        tr.closest('tr').css({ "display": "none" });
    }
    $('table tr').each(function (item) {
        var itemPai = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
        if (item == itemPai) {
            console.log("Tem filhos");
            $(this).closest('tr').find('a.toggler').css({ "display": "normal" });
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('a.toggler').css({ "display": "" });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just to note, `tr.closest('tr')` is functionally the same at just using `tr` (same for `$(this).closest('tr')`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, might be helpful to know which kind of data do you have in your table.

Can you be sure that values of cells you access are numbers? if not 100%, use `typeof` before you use `parseInt`.

Anyway, in the second loop the variable `item` from the outer loop is available, declaring it in the function call as a parameter will override the outer value.

If what you want is to compare values between the outer and inner loop, simply remove the parameter from the function call of inner iteration:

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
  var tr = $(this)
  var nivel = parseInt(tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
  var item = parseInt(tr.find('td:eq(0)').text());
  if (nivel > 3) {
    tr.closest('tr').css({ "display": "none" });
  }
  $('table tr').each(function () {
    var itemPai = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
    if (item == itemPai) {
      console.log("Tem filhos");
      $(this).closest('tr').find('a.toggler').css({ "display": "normal" });
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('a.toggler').css({ "display": "" });
    }
  });
});
```